# sdoc gem install yields unexpcted results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

My Environment:

```
OS: Windows 8.1 
Ruby version: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [x64-mingw32] 
MySQL/Apache: AMPPS and both MySQL and Apache are running
```

I am trying to install the sdoc gem using the following command (from Windows powershell):

gem install sdoc

Here's what I get:

```
rdoc's executable "rdoc" conflicts with C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rdoc
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  n
```

I did not want it overwriting anything, so I typed n. Here's what I get in response:

```
ERROR:  Error installing sdoc:
    "rdoc" from rdoc conflicts with C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rdoc
```

Is sdoc misidentifying itself as rdoc? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at sdoc's [gemspec](https://github.com/voloko/sdoc/blob/master/sdoc.gemspec), you'll see that it has `rdoc ~> 4.0, < 5.0` specified as a dependency. That means that installing `sdoc` will include a version of `rdoc` that is between versions 4 and 5.

That is why your current version of `rdoc` is conflicting with `sdoc` installation. If you really want sdoc and your current version of `rdoc` is not the latest stable one, just go ahead and overwrite it. :)